# Finding intersections between given equations and d-dimensional polytope

Tags: computational-geometry

I am currently storing a $d$-dimensional polytope as a list of $d$-dimensional points.

In order to implement an algorithm, I need to find intersections between my polytope and $d$ equations, of the form:

\begin{align}
    x_1 &= c_1 \\
    x_2 &= c_2 \\
    &\dots \\
    x_d &= c_d \\
\end{align}
where $x_i$ is a coordinate in the $d$-dimensional plane, and $c_i$ is some given constant.
I'm sorry for the none accurate description - I wasn't sure if those equations are called a line, a plane, a hyperplane etc.

My question is, what would be the best way to do so?

Currently I am trying to find all the facets of the polytope, and intersect each facet with all the equations. That might be too slow, and also, more importantly for now - I'm not sure how to know which vertices define a facet.

I'd really appreciate suggestions!

Comment: You can use linear programming to find an arbitrary point of intersection. Maximize or minimize the corresponding coordinate to find the "top" and "bottom" intersections.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus I tried doing so, but I think it wouldn't be optimal in runtime, and most importantly - I ran into the problem of converting vertices to hyperfaces - I don't know how to define the equations of the hyperfaces of the polytope, given the vertices. I know I can do something very similiar, using a Convex Hull algorithm, but my problem is that the polytope might not be convex.

Comment: Suppose the points are $p_1,\ldots,p_n$. The LP has variables $0 \leq a_1,\ldots,a_n \leq 1$ such that $\sum_{i=1}^n a_i = 1$. Add the constraint $\sum_{i=1}^n a_i (p_i)_j = c_j$. A solution to this LP is a point in the intersection. You seem however to be interested actually in the intersection of the hyperplane $x_j = c_j$ with the *boundary* of the polytope. As you vary $c_j$, you will visit all facets of the polytope, so perhaps there is no hope to avoid a complexity which depends on the number of facets.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus what is the meaning of the `ai` values? Will it still work on non-convex polytopes? And thank you so much for your help! :)

Comment: They define a convex combination of your vertices.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus will it work on concave polytopes, without triangulating / other methods of transforming concave polytope into convex parts then? If so, what is the mathematical reasoning behind that? Thank you so much! Toda Raba! :)

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "concave polytope". A polytope is the convex hull of a set of points. There might be such a thing as concave polytope, but I doubt that you can define it just by giving a list of its vertices.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus I guess I was referring to [this definition by Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polytope). I'm talking about cases which look like the green 2-dimensional polygon, in the link, but in d-dimensions - cases where more than 2 facets intersect with the same equation from the given equations. Sorry for misleading.

Comment: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/150552/755