# Intersecting multiple rays with a polytope

Tags: computational-geometry

I have multiple rays of the form:

\begin{align}
    x_1 &= c_1 \\
    x_2 &= c_2 \\
    &\dots \\
    x_d &= c_d \\
\end{align}

And need to find all intersection points between each one of them and a given polytope in $d$ dimensions, when I have the vertices and the $d-1$ polytopes which are his facets.
For 3-d, [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intersection_of_a_polyhedron_with_a_line) says in the last line that it's possible to do so in logarithmic time per query. Is there a way to do something similiar in arbitrary dimensions? Or is there a decent approach to this problem? I can't assume that the polytope or his facets are convex, so ways using convex combinations are not good for me sadly.

Comment: With such an equation, your "rays" are single points, no ?

Comment: I don't understand what your rays are.  Also, why do you assume that polytope in $d$ dimensions has $d-1$ facets?  Have you tried reading the paper that Wikipedia cites to see what you can learn from it?

Comment: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/150351/755

Comment: @D.W. Perhaps I didn't express myself correctly - by the definition I saw on Wikipedia, a facet of a $d$ dimensional polytope, is a $d-1$ dimensional polytope. That's what I meant. My rays are basically just a plane (I think that's the definition) of the form 0x_1 + 0x_2 + .... + 1x_j + 0x_(j+1) = c_j
And I have $d$ different planes. I want t find every intersection point of each plane with the facets of the $d$ dimensional polytope. Not every intersection point of all planes and the polytope.

Comment: $d-1$ facets is different from $d-1$-dimensional facets.  A ray is a linear subset of dimension 1.  A plane is not a ray.  Please don't clarifications in the comment.  Instead, please [edit] the question so it is clear and reads well for someone who encounters it for the first time.